# How to use a class attribute instead of a global variable?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to have a variable that is common to many functions so I thought about using a global variable but I saw that it was a bad idea and that it's better to work with a class so I guess we should use a class attribute?

The real question is how can I go from a program that relies on a global variable to a program that uses a class attribute?

Let's say for example I have the following :

`function.py` :

```
my_variable = []

def function1():
    global my_variable
    #then we do something on my_variable
def function2():
    global my_variable
    #then we do something on my_variable
```

`views.py` (in flask) :

```
from function import my_variable
@app.route('/'):
    global my_variable 
    function1()
    function2()
    return my_variable
```

I guess with a class we would have something like this for `function.py` ?

```
class Function:

    my_variable = []
    def __init__(self, variable):
        Function.my_variable = variable
    def function1(self):
    #we do something on Function.my_variable
    def function2(self):
    #we do something on Function.my_variable
```

Is this a good start ?

Comment: `Function.my_variable = variable` is a serious antipattern since it creates *global state*, the same for `global my_variable`s, etc.

Comment: "*Is this a good start?*"  Yes.  Is this a good practice?  Probably not.  Good luck following the value/state of `Function.my_variable` while debugging.

Comment: Where did you read that it's better to have a class? It still has to be in the global namespace to make use of it.

Comment: It is good to minimize the use of globals, but having a couple of  _mutable_ globals that you only mutate and _never_ assign to isn't so bad. With those, you don't need a `global` statement in the functions that mutate the global variable's contents, that's only needed if you want to perform an assignment to a global name.

Comment: Having global state is especially problematic in a web app like Flask, as you will almost certainly have multiple users. Are you sure you want the state to be shared across all users?

Comment: Then how can I improve it?  I posted a small program on a forum and someone told me that using a global variable isn't the best idea, I looked it up on the internet and I found sources that shared the same idea. @Daniel Roseman I don't know, I am still a beginner so I am trying to find a solution to my problem, my web app works with 5 files on the disk and I should be able to add, delete or modify entries in the files. The global variable was supposed to be used to get a file's content and from then I work on/with it to influence a file's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards the pro's and con's of why **globals** are so evil in Python, I'm going to refer you to the following page that I used myself when researching this very thing a while ago:

[Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

What I find interesting is that I am using a Python linter in Visual Studio Code (my IDE of choice) and this linter **always** highlights globals as being a problem even when implemented correctly. Between the linter errors and the advice in the link that I shared, I followed the same rule you've already mentioned. Use **class** variables instead of **global** ones in Python.

As for how to make your global variables into class variables? It's quite straightforward.

So what you have above is a module where you're declaring your `my_variable` and initialising it as an empty list. So in a class, you can do the same thing as follows:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_variable = []
```

Or if you want to assign the value to the variable directly when you instantiate an instance of this class, you can also do the following:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, my_variable):
        self.my_variable = my_variable
```

So now you can create an instance of your `MyClass` by using:

```
myClass = MyClass() #For the first example OR
myClass = MyClass([]) #For the second example
```

So now we want to change the values of the `my_variable` part of `MyClass` so lets do that. You can pretty much use the same function style as you're used to from your global variables for this. Just note that in order to re-assign `my_variable` to a new value within the class, you'll need to use the `self` keyword when referring to it, since it now belongs to a `class`, as follows:

```
def function1(self):
    self.my_variable = #Change the value of my_variable

def function2(self):
    self.my_variable = #Change the value of my_variable again
```

So your entire `class` now looks like this:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_variable = []

    def function1(self):
        self.my_variable = #Change the value of my_variable

    def function2(self):
        self.my_variable = #Change the value of my_variable again
```

So now you've converted your `global` variable to a `class` variable but how can we use it? First, lets assume that your class `MyClass` is stored in a file called `my_class.py`. Going by your Flask method example, you now do the following:

```
from my_class import MyClass

    @app.route('/'):
        myClass = MyClass() 
        myClass.function1()
        myClass.function2()
        return myClass.my_variable
```

And this will work exactly as you need it to!

Comment: Very happy to help! Happy coding with Python!

Comment: Technically speaking I think you're talking about instance variables (defined and used in an instance). But I get the intent of your answer. Upvoted!